# Select users with a difference larger than zero between the last two entries in a specific table with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the [SQLFiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e1b3/1) to my tables.

I basically want to select only Jack and Jill, as there is a non-zero difference between the last two `num`s entries of the table `foo` with the `user` being their respective names.

How is this possible?

Note: just to mention, in my `foo` table, I have around 100000 rows, so it would be good if there was a very quick and fast way of retrieving the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer doing this using `limit` with the offset to get the two most recent values.  Happily, your table has an `id` column for determining the order.

```
select user,
       (select num from foo f2 where f2.user = f.user order by f2.id desc limit 1
       ) lastval,
       (select num from foo f2 where f2.user = f.user order by f2.id desc limit 1, 2
       ) lastval2
from foo f
group by user
having lastval <> lastval2
```

Comment: it seems to be slow, though I can't find why in your code. Your code does seem good, at any extent?

Comment: @thnk123 . . . It needs to sort the data twice by id.  If you have an index on `foo(user, id)`, then it should run quite fast.

Comment: It is doing 2 correlated subqueries which are likely to perform poorly

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way (although I think you'd be more likely to JOIN on a user's id rather than their name!?!...

```
SELECT u.* 
  FROM
     ( SELECT x.*, COUNT(*) rank FROM foo x JOIN foo y ON y.user = x.user AND y.id >= x.id GROUP BY x.id)a
  LEFT
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.*, COUNT(*) rank FROM foo x JOIN foo y ON y.user = x.user AND y.id >= x.id GROUP BY x.id)b
    ON b.user = a.user 
   AND b.num = a.num
   AND b.rank = a.rank + 1
  JOIN users u
    ON u.user = a.user
 WHERE b.id IS NULL
   AND a.rank = 1;
```

I think this query can be rewritten as follows, which might be faster...

```
SELECT u.* 
  FROM
     ( SELECT id
            , user
            , num
            , @prev_user := @curr_user
            , @curr_user := user
            , @rank := IF(@prev_user = @curr_user, @rank+1, @rank:=1) rank
         FROM foo
         JOIN (SELECT @curr_user := null, @prev_user := null, @rank := 0) sel1
        ORDER 
           BY user
            , id DESC
     ) a
  LEFT
  JOIN
       ( SELECT id
            , user
            , num
            , @prev_user := @curr_user
            , @curr_user := user
            , @rank := IF(@prev_user = @curr_user, @rank+1, @rank:=1) rank
         FROM foo
         JOIN (SELECT @curr_user := null, @prev_user := null, @rank := 0) sel1
        ORDER 
           BY user
            , id DESC
     ) b
    ON b.user = a.user 
   AND b.num = a.num
   AND b.rank = a.rank + 1
  JOIN users u
    ON u.user = a.user
 WHERE b.id IS NULL
   AND a.rank = 1;
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my question properly. I want to check if there is a difference between the last two `num` values of the same person - if there is, select his user profile. If not, don't select it.

Comment: In which case, I don't you understood my answer!

Comment: Query is working fine with one little change. OP asked "non-zero difference between the last two" and this query will return the first two. In example there are only two per user so it's the same, but if you add more rows it will return the same result set not accounting for later entries. 
Only thing needs changing is JOIN clause in both subqueries - from <= to >=
DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bcdf/1

Comment: ! ! ! oops ! ! ! - but to be fair, OP did say 'Jack' and 'Jill'

Comment: I'll upvote and accept, but is there any way you can speed up the query, so it doesn't have the run through the whole `foo` table, as I have more than 100,000 rows in the `foo` table.

Comment: Have you tried the other solutions? Can you post your real data?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Strawberrys 2nd solution I have tried this.

```
SELECT user, MIN(num) AS MinNum, MAX(num) AS MaxNum
FROM (   SELECT id
            , user
            , num
            , @prev_user := @curr_user
            , @curr_user := user
            , @rank := IF(@prev_user = @curr_user, @rank+1, 1) AS rank
FROM foo
JOIN (SELECT @curr_user := null, @prev_user := null, @rank := 1) sel1
ORDER BY user, id DESC
) AS Sub
WHERE rank <= 2
GROUP BY user
HAVING MinNum != MaxNum
```

This is getting the details ranked as a subselect and rejecting where the rank is greater than 2 (unfortunately the user variables give strange results if you try and check this within the subselect). The results are then grouped on user and the min and max value of num are returned. If they are different then the row is returned (and as you only have 1 or 2 rows per user, the min and max will only be different if there are 2 rows returned AND they have different values).

Advantage of this is that it avoids joining 2 100000 sets against each other and also only needs to do the ranking once (although you would hope that MySQL would optimise this 2nd issue away anyway).